# How to pass endpoint details dynamically from configuration?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core

I followed [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/06/26/wcf-connected-service-for-net-core-1-0-0-and-asp-net-core-1-0-0-is-now-available/) to include WCF service into my ASP.NET core application.

Looking at below line in reference.cs, it seems default endpoint configuration is hard-coded inside reference.cs.

```
return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://localhost:49945/SimpleService.svc");
```

This is how I can create my client in asp.net core controller-

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:49945/SimpleService.svc");
            wcfClient = new SimpleServiceClient(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
```

So my questions are-

1. Where should I maintain endpoint details so that it can be easily configurable during deployment?
2. **How I can pass endpoint details (address and binding) dynamically** from configuration file (appsetting.json)?

Generated Reference.cs file looks like follows-

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     //
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace SimpleServiceReference
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "0.5.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="CompositeType", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SimpleService")]
    public partial class CompositeType : object
    {

        private bool BoolValueField;

        private string StringValueField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.BoolValueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.BoolValueField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.StringValueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.StringValueField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "0.5.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="SimpleServiceReference.ISimpleService")]
    public interface ISimpleService
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISimpleService/GetData", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISimpleService/GetDataResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetDataAsync(int value);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISimpleService/GetDataUsingDataContract", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISimpleService/GetDataUsingDataContractResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SimpleServiceReference.CompositeType> GetDataUsingDataContractAsync(SimpleServiceReference.CompositeType composite);
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "0.5.0.0")]
    public interface ISimpleServiceChannel : SimpleServiceReference.ISimpleService, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
    {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "0.5.0.0")]
    public partial class SimpleServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<SimpleServiceReference.ISimpleService>, SimpleServiceReference.ISimpleService
    {

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
    /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
    static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);

        public SimpleServiceClient() : 
                base(SimpleServiceClient.GetDefaultBinding(), SimpleServiceClient.GetDefaultEndpointAddress())
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public SimpleServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) : 
                base(SimpleServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), SimpleServiceClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public SimpleServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(SimpleServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(remoteAddress))
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public SimpleServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(SimpleServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), remoteAddress)
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public SimpleServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetDataAsync(int value)
        {
            return base.Channel.GetDataAsync(value);
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SimpleServiceReference.CompositeType> GetDataUsingDataContractAsync(SimpleServiceReference.CompositeType composite)
        {
            return base.Channel.GetDataUsingDataContractAsync(composite);
        }

        public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task OpenAsync()
        {
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginOpen(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndOpen));
        }

        public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task CloseAsync()
        {
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginClose(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndClose));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService))
            {
                System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
                result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.AllowCookies = true;
                return result;
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService))
            {
                return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://localhost:49945/SimpleService.svc");
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetDefaultBinding()
        {
            return SimpleServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService);
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetDefaultEndpointAddress()
        {
            return SimpleServiceClient.GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService);
        }

        public enum EndpointConfiguration
        {

            BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I needed the same thing in the past, and ended up storing the connection details for a WCF service in the app's options. I stored the details in the appsettings.json file, created an Options class, and registered it with the services setup logic so I could request it when creating the WCF service.

Bare with my code, I just whipped this up quickly. I have not tested it for common errors like missing braces, semicolons, or misspellings :-P

**Options class**

```
public class MyServiceOptions
{
    public string EndpointUrl {get;set;}
}
```

**Excerpt from startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<MyServiceOptions>Configuration.GetSection("MyService"));
    //Other calls as needed...

}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "MyService": {
        "EndpointUrl": "http://localhost:49945/SimpleService.svc"
    }
}
```

Then you can access your options by requesting an instance of `IOptions<MyServiceOptions>` from the dependency injection container in a variaty of ways.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    //Option 1, in controller constructor
    private IOptions<MyServiceOptions> myOptions;

    public MyController(IOptions<MyServiceOptions> myOptions1)
    {
        myOptions = myOptions1
    }

    //Option 2, in action method signature
    public IActionResult MyAction([FromServices]IOptions<MyServiceOptions> myOptions2)
    {
        //Option 3, directly
        var myOptions3 = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IControllerFactory>();
        //NOTE: The GetService<>() method is an extension method from the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection namespace


        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(myOptions.Value.EndpointUrl);
        wcfClient = new SimpleServiceClient(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will solve address part. but Binding part is still hardcoded right? Earlier, we used to have this configuration - `<endpoint address="http://localhost:49945/SimpleService"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService"
                contract="ServiceReference1.ISimpleService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService">` Which was easier to modify during deployments.

Comment: That used to be done via the asp.net config files, which MVC Core (and .NET Core) doesn't use any more. Instead, configuration details should be in the AppSettings. If you need alternate bindings (http, versus https, other transport settings, etc) You'll likely have to manually handle this by putting flags/settings on your Options class and manually deal with them in your code. If there's a way to define the configuration for the WCF bindings in ASP.NET Core and have it automatically wire everything up for you, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Thanks Nick for your feedback